# Insert links between comment tags in README.md in Go

Tags: regex, go, regexp-replace

I want to insert links between comment tags in my `README.md` file as I am generating the links dynamically. I wrote a function to do exactly that but the issue is it replaces the comment tags as well. I need to modify my function to insert the links between the comment tags and not replacing it as a whole.

```
//README.md

### HTTP APIs

<!--HTTP-API-start-->

<!--HTTP-API-end-->

### AMQP APIs

<!--AMQP-API-start-->

<!--AMQP-API-end-->
```

Here's the function I wrote to insert the links. A possible solution would be to append the comment tags along with `httpAPI` and `AmqpAPI` strings, but it is not what I am looking for as it replaces the current tags it the file.

```golang
func GenerateGodocLinkInReadme(amqpLinks string, httpLinks string) {

    path := `../../README.md`
    formattedContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    httpAPI := "<!--HTTP-API-start-->" +
        amqpLinks +
        "\n" +
        "<!--HTTP-API-end-->"

    AmqpAPI := "<!--AMQP-API-start-->" +
        httpLinks +
        "\n" +
        "<!--AMQP-API-end-->"

    formattedContent = regexp.MustCompile(`<!--AMQP-API-start-->([\s\S]*?)<!--AMQP-API-end-->`).ReplaceAll(formattedContent, []byte(AmqpAPI))
    exitOnFail(ioutil.WriteFile(path, formattedContent, 0644))
    formattedContent = regexp.MustCompile(`<!--HTTP-API-start-->([\s\S]*?)<!--HTTP-API-end-->`).ReplaceAll(formattedContent, []byte(httpAPI))
    exitOnFail(ioutil.WriteFile(path, formattedContent, 0644))
}
```

This function works correctly but it replaces the comment tags as well. I need to modify this function so that it inserts the links between the comment tags.

Comment: Add these tags to  httpAPI, AmqpAPI to write them too. this code replace tags becase the pattern has them.

Comment: I already did that and it works but it is not the solution I am looking for as it replaces the contents of ``README.md``.

Comment: Is your problem just that you want links to be added and not replaced?

Comment: Yes. I want to add my links between those tags and not replacing everything.

Comment: Well, you can get the links between those tags and add new links to them and rewrite the file.

Comment: Can you rewrite the function along with regex and post it as an answer if you can please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```py
func GenerateGodocLinkInReadme(amqpLinks string, httpLinks string) {
    path := `README.md`
    formattedContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    amqpRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`<!--AMQP-API-start-->([\s\S]*?)<!--AMQP-API-end-->`)
    httpRegex := regexp.MustCompile(`<!--HTTP-API-start-->([\s\S]*?)<!--HTTP-API-end-->`)

    prevAmqpLinks := string(amqpRegex.FindSubmatch((formattedContent))[1]) // Second index of returns links between tags
    prevHttpLinks := string(httpRegex.FindSubmatch((formattedContent))[1]) // Second index of returns links between tags
    httpAPI := prevHttpLinks + httpLinks + "\n"
    AmqpAPI := prevAmqpLinks + amqpLinks + "\n"
    formattedContent = amqpRegex.ReplaceAll(formattedContent, []byte(`<!--AMQP-API-start-->` + AmqpAPI + `<!--AMQP-API-end-->`))
    formattedContent = httpRegex.ReplaceAll(formattedContent, []byte(`<!--HTTP-API-start-->` + httpAPI + `<!--HTTP-API-end-->`))
    exitOnFail(ioutil.WriteFile(path, formattedContent, 0644))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But I have already tried appending it with comment tags and it works as same as your code. I have updated my code for your reference.

Comment: You did not add the links was between the tags before but, in this code `prevAmqpLinks` and `prevHttpLinks` get the links was there before and new links added to them. i tested that and works fine.